# Perl prometheus gauge add label with set_function does not give the expected result

Tags: perl, prometheus

I'm trying to add a label to a prometheus gauge. Using the set method works just fine, but it seems like I can't get the set_function method right.

The result is that I just don't see the gauge metric where I used the set_function method.

The result(cleaned up) is as follows:

```
# HELP Test Test help 
# TYPE Test gauge
```

Whats expected is a third line saying "Test{color="red"} 123"

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/H3wStgW7) to the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Net::Prometheus;

my $client = Net::Prometheus->new;

$client->new_gauge(name => "Test", help => "Test help", labels => [qw/color/])->set_function('red', sub { return 123 });

print $client->render;
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if it's a bug?

Prometheus [new_gauge->new_function()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Prometheus::Gauge#set_function)

> METHODS
>
> **set**
>
> $gauge->set( [ @label_values ], $value )
> $child->set($value )
>
> *Sets the current value for the gauge.*
>
> *If the gauge has any labels defined, the values for them must be given
> first.*
>
> **set_function**
>
> $gauge->set_function( [ @label_values ], $func )
> $child->set_function( $func )
>
> *Sets a value-returning callback function
> for the gauge. If the gauge is labeled, each label combination
> requires its own function.*
>
> *When invoked, the function will be passed no arguments and is expected
> to return a single value*

Comment: Is Mojolicious relevant to your problem? Your reduced code outputs the expected string for me: `use Net::Prometheus; my $c = Net::Prometheus->new(); $c->new_gauge(help=>'',name=>'Test3',labels=>['color']);->set('red',123);print $c->render` outputs `Test3{color="red"} 123`.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I was using Mojolicious in the original code, so for some reason I did it in the example as well. Have changed it to a better example without it. The set method works fine, but the set_function does not, by the looks of it.

Comment: This was reported as a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127284) now

Comment: Yes, I sent one in. It's been fixed in version 0.06.
https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the intended approach with [Net::Prometheus](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Prometheus), but creating a gauge, setting a value and then setting a function works for me:

```
my $c = Net::Prometheus->new;
my $g = $c->new_gauge(name=>'Test',help=>'help',labels=>['color']);
$g->set('red',1);
$g->set_function('red',sub { warn 'Getter called'; 123 });
print $c->render
```

This outputs

```
Getter called at ...
# HELP Test help
# TYPE Test gauge
Test{color="red"} 123
```

I think the documentation could be a bit clearer about this.

This has been addressed in the [0.06 release](https://metacpan.org/release/PEVANS/Net-Prometheus-0.06).

Comment: Yeah, it should either be documented or (if it's a bug) fixed in the code. The [relevant code](https://metacpan.org/source/PEVANS/Net-Prometheus-0.05/lib/Net/Prometheus/Gauge.pm#L182-194) only pays attention to `values` (which are created by `set`). It dynamically calls functions (if they exist), but you need to have a `value` first.

Comment: Yes, I sent in a bug report. It's been fixed in version 0.06. rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127284